# Trouble With Identifier Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to list the order ID, order date, customer ID, customer first name, customer last name, and customer phone number for all orders on or before 1/26/13.  Sort by order date then by customer ID, both in ascending order.  Format the date as “mm-dd-yyyy” and use the following column headings:  OrderID, OrderDate, CustID, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustPhone.

But I am receiving an error saying "ORD."CUST_ID": Invalid identifier

Here is my code

```
 SELECT ORD.Order_ID as OrderID, to_char(Order_Date,'mm-dd-yyyy') as OrderDate, C.Cust_ID as 
 CustID, Cust_FName as CustFirstName, Cust_LName as CustLastName, Cust_Phone as CustPhone
 FROM ORDER_arb ORD, CUSTOMER_arb C
 INNER JOIN ORDER_arb ON C.Cust_ID = ORD.Cust_ID
 WHERE Order_Date <= '26-JAN-13'
 ORDER BY Order_Date, Cust_ID;
```

I would appreciate your help, Thanks

Comment: Oracle...my apologies for making MySQL a tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing implicit and explicit `join` syntax.  I think the problem is that you have the `ORDER_ARB` table twice in the `FROM` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT ORD.Order_ID as OrderID, to_char(ORD.Order_Date, 'mm-dd-yyyy') as OrderDate,
       C.Cust_ID as CustID, C.Cust_FName as CustFirstName, C.Cust_LName as CustLastName,
       C.Cust_Phone as CustPhone
FROM CUSTOMER_arb C INNER JOIN
     ORDER_arb ORD
     ON C.Cust_ID = ORD.Cust_ID
WHERE ORD.Order_Date <= '26-JAN-13'
ORDER BY ORD.Order_Date, C.Cust_ID;
```

Comment: good thought- but I still get a "column ambiguously defined" error under Cust_ID

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your query seems to be here

```
 FROM ORDER_arb ORD, CUSTOMER_arb C   INNER JOIN 
   ORDER_arb    -- no alias here 
      ON C.Cust_ID = ORD.Cust_ID ---   here you have given ORD as alias
```

Give a different alias for **ORDER_arb** table and try

This might help you,

```
SELECT ORD.Order_ID as OrderID, to_char(Order_Date,'mm-dd-yyyy') as OrderDate, C.Cust_ID as 
CustID, Cust_FName as CustFirstName, Cust_LName as CustLastName, Cust_Phone as      CustPhone
FROM ORDER_arb ORD, CUSTOMER_arb C
INNER JOIN 
ORDER_arb  OR_AB ON C.Cust_ID = OR_AB.Cust_ID
 WHERE Order_Date <= '26-JAN-13'
  ORDER BY Order_Date, Cust_ID;
```